# Echo queries differently based on type in Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Using Mysqli, I'm trying to distinguish queries where they differ by types.
Each query has either type 1 or type 2. What I'm trying to do is post all the queries that are type 1 in a div class called "typeonecontent" and all those that are type 2 in a div called "typetwocontent".

Using this code, I'm calling all queries that are type 1 but type 2 still need to be called too, just differently as I stated. How would I need to go about that without duplicating the entire code and making changes to every variable, because this underlying chunk of code doesn't end here?

```
 include_once("config.php"); //this is the database connection
    $query = "SELECT * FROM blogpages WHERE type = 1"; //selects from the table called blogpages    
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);


    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) //if user is logged in
    {   
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
    $pagetitle = $row['pagetitle'];
    $message = $row['message'];


    echo  //echo the content
        '<article class="typeonecontent">                       
           <div class="mct">
                <h2>
                    '.$pagetitle .'</h2>
           </div><br>
           <p class="post-text"><br>    
                    '.$message.'</p>                          
          </article> ';
```

Comment: The thing is, I'm actually stuck in the logic of it. I've tried making the article class as shown above a variable that changes to either typeonecontent or typeonecontent based on which button is clicked for the query to be inserted. But that doesn't work either. I'm not that great using PHP.

Comment: Following up on @splash58 first steps to help you start to provide more details to those willing to help: What is a type 2 query in principle, how did you codify it, is this trusted or untrusted input (user provided or hard wired in literals assigned to variables, etc.